# How to escape the NÃO while reading the URL

Tags: java, utf-8

```
InputStream in = address.openStream();
URL url = new URL("://www.mydomain.com/?param1=NÃO&param2=NÃO");   
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();   
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

But when i am trying to put the result into StringBuilder the NÃO Special character Ã is getting escaped 
How to bring it with out losing the char set value ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want to use [`URLEncoder.encode(String, String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html#encode%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to encode your parameter like

```
try {
    String value = URLEncoder.encode("NÃO", "utf-8");
    String url = "://www.mydomain.com/?param1=" + value + "&param2="
            + value;
    System.out.println(url);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is

```
://www.mydomain.com/?param1=N%C3%83O&param2=N%C3%83O
```